# explanation of wait_event_timeout

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I've got some part of linux kernel sources:

```
#define wait_event_timeout(wq, condition, timeout)                      \
({                                                                      \
        long __ret = timeout;                                           \
        if (!(condition))                                               \
                __wait_event_timeout(wq, condition, __ret);             \
        __ret;                                                          \
})
```

and I cannot understand what does the last "__ret;" do?

Can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a **C** problem: `__ret` is the return value of that macro. It is also written in the [comment above that macro](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/wait.h#L272)